# How to use chart.js with a JSON dictionary

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart

I am trying to make a bar chart from a JSON dictionary, but it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
new Chart("log", {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: Object.keys(log),
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: barColors,
      data: [ Object.values(log)]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false},
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Historial de logueo"
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero:true,
          fontColor:"#8f9092",
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

log is a dictionary like this: {'somedate':somenumber}

I want 'log' keys to be x and values to be y. It shows the key as x value, but no graph. However, if i put "Object.values(log)[0]" in data, it works. Obviously, it only works as long as there is 1 value.

Comment: Did you mean `Object.values(log)` instead of `[ Object.values(log) ]`? [`Object.values`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) returns an Array. Putting it into another array seems incorrect.

Comment: i apparently can't upvote you but i believe this was it. nothing like a good sintax error to make one humble